# How can two functions be compared?

Tags: complex-analysis

> If the derivatives of all orders for two functions agree at one point how can two functions be compared?

There's no mention about the domain of those two functions. Can I suppose them to be equal?

- **Added:** If they are holomorphic at the point $z_0$ then of course they are equal in a neighborhood of $z_0$ which is evident from their Taylor series representation of those two functions.

Comment: Your tag says [tag:complex-analysis], does this mean you talk about holomorphic functions?

Comment: @K.Stm.: They are not mentioned to be holomorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic function on an open set $\Omega$ of the complex plane and for some $z_0\in\Omega$, $f^{(n)}(z_0)=g^{(n)}(z_0)$ for each $n$, then $f=g$ on the connected component of $\Omega$ where $z_0$ belongs.

To see that, look at the power series at $z_0$ of $f-g$: this proves that $f-g$ is $0$ on a ball containing $z_0$.

The case of functions of a *real* variable is radically different, for example with 
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac 1{x^2}\right), &\mbox{ if }x\neq 0;\\
0&\mbox{ if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @K.Stm. I didn't notice he deleted his answer. I wrote the example.

Comment: Do $f''$ exists at $z_0$ imply $f'$ exists in a nbd of $z_0?$

Comment: Yes (in order to make the definition of derivative sense).

Comment: To make the derivative sense isn't it enough for $z_0$ to be a limit point of $\text{dom }f'?$